# How to read ManagementObject Collection in WMI using C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi

I found a code on net and have been trying to get more information about **mo[]**.

I am trying to get all the information contained in ManagementObjectCollection.

Since parameter in **mo** is looking for an string value which I dont know, how can I get all the values without knowing its parameter values. Or if I want to get all the indexer values related to mo in `ManagementObjectCollection`

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objOSDetails = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = objOSDetails.Get();

foreach( ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection )
{ 
   _osName  = mo["name"].ToString();// what other fields are there other than name
   _osVesion = mo["version"].ToString();
   _loginName = mo["csname"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Take a look at your WMI query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem
```

It means "get all instances of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx) class and include all class properties". This is a clue that the resulting `ManagementObject`s are wrappers over the WMI `Win32_OperatingSystem` class. See the [class description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx) to learn what properties it has, what they mean and to decide which ones you actually need to use in your code.

If you need to iterate through all available properties without hard-coding their names, use the [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties.aspx) property like as [Giorgi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523844/how-to-read-managementobject-collection-in-wmi-using-c/3523870#3523870). Here's an example:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection)
{
    foreach (PropertyData prop in mo.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the System is win 8 or 8.1 running 64 bit OS?What class to be used then !

Comment: @Raulp: The same classes. WMI classes are bitness-agnostic.

Answer (score 14):

Use [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx) first so you know what the property means.  Experiment with the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) tool.

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate through all properties using [Properties Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties.aspx)