# How to get Bus Reported Device Description using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a value from windows device manager(windows 7).

The property name i am searching for is Bus Reported Device Description.

I am using the below code to get device name.

Please help me to get the Bus reported device description.

```
 void OtherDevices()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher deviceList = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name, Status from Win32_PnPEntity");
        if (deviceList != null)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject device in deviceList.Get())
            {
                string name = device.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
                if (name.Contains("iC5000"))
                {
                    dgv_HWlist.Rows.Add(name);
                    // break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523844/how-to-read-managementobject-collection-in-wmi-using-c-sharp AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties.aspx

Answer (score -8, accepted):

```
string description = (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description");
```

Comment: I am getting exception : Not found

Comment: This code just giving the description but not the bus reported device description. Please help.

Comment: This just returns the "Description" (usually set by the device INF file), not the "Bus reported device description" (which can be set by the USB device, for instance)

Answer (score 8):

```
namespace flash_tool.common.Utils
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Win32DeviceMgmt
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum DiGetClassFlags : uint
        {
            DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001,  // only valid with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
            DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002,
            DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004,
            DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008,
            DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010,
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Device registry property codes
        /// </summary>
        public enum SPDRP : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// DeviceDesc (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = 0x00000000,

            /// <summary>
            /// HardwareID (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001,

            /// <summary>
            /// CompatibleIDs (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS = 0x00000002,

            /// <summary>
            /// unused
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UNUSED0 = 0x00000003,

            /// <summary>
            /// Service (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_SERVICE = 0x00000004,

            /// <summary>
            /// unused
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UNUSED1 = 0x00000005,

            /// <summary>
            /// unused
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UNUSED2 = 0x00000006,

            /// <summary>
            /// Class (R--tied to ClassGUID)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_CLASS = 0x00000007,

            /// <summary>
            /// ClassGUID (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_CLASSGUID = 0x00000008,

            /// <summary>
            /// Driver (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_DRIVER = 0x00000009,

            /// <summary>
            /// ConfigFlags (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS = 0x0000000A,

            /// <summary>
            /// Mfg (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_MFG = 0x0000000B,

            /// <summary>
            /// FriendlyName (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME = 0x0000000C,

            /// <summary>
            /// LocationInformation (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION = 0x0000000D,

            /// <summary>
            /// PhysicalDeviceObjectName (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME = 0x0000000E,

            /// <summary>
            /// Capabilities (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_CAPABILITIES = 0x0000000F,

            /// <summary>
            /// UiNumber (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UI_NUMBER = 0x00000010,

            /// <summary>
            /// UpperFilters (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UPPERFILTERS = 0x00000011,

            /// <summary>
            /// LowerFilters (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_LOWERFILTERS = 0x00000012,

            /// <summary>
            /// BusTypeGUID (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID = 0x00000013,

            /// <summary>
            /// LegacyBusType (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_LEGACYBUSTYPE = 0x00000014,

            /// <summary>
            /// BusNumber (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_BUSNUMBER = 0x00000015,

            /// <summary>
            /// Enumerator Name (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME = 0x00000016,

            /// <summary>
            /// Security (R/W, binary form)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_SECURITY = 0x00000017,

            /// <summary>
            /// Security (W, SDS form)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_SECURITY_SDS = 0x00000018,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Type (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_DEVTYPE = 0x00000019,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device is exclusive-access (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_EXCLUSIVE = 0x0000001A,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Characteristics (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_CHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000001B,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Address (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_ADDRESS = 0x0000001C,

            /// <summary>
            /// UiNumberDescFormat (R/W)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_UI_NUMBER_DESC_FORMAT = 0X0000001D,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Power Data (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA = 0x0000001E,

            /// <summary>
            /// Removal Policy (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY = 0x0000001F,

            /// <summary>
            /// Hardware Removal Policy (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_HW_DEFAULT = 0x00000020,

            /// <summary>
            /// Removal Policy Override (RW)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_OVERRIDE = 0x00000021,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Install State (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE = 0x00000022,

            /// <summary>
            /// Device Location Paths (R)
            /// </summary>
            SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS = 0x00000023,
        }
        private const UInt32 DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL = 0x00000001;
        private const UInt32 DIREG_DEV = 0x00000001;
        private const UInt32 KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 0x0001;

        /// <summary>
        /// The SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure defines a device instance that is a member of a device information set.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
        {
            public UInt32 cbSize;
            public Guid ClassGuid;
            public UInt32 DevInst;
            public UIntPtr Reserved;
        };


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct DEVPROPKEY
        {
            public Guid fmtid;
            public UInt32 pid;
        }


        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        private static extern Int32 SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, UInt32 MemberIndex, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid gClass, UInt32 iEnumerator, UInt32 hParent, DiGetClassFlags nFlags);

        [DllImport("Setupapi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(IntPtr hDeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData, uint scope,
            uint hwProfile, uint parameterRegistryValueKind, uint samDesired);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "RegQueryValueExW", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int RegQueryValueEx(IntPtr hKey, string lpValueName, int lpReserved, out uint lpType,
            byte[] lpData, ref uint lpcbData);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int RegCloseKey(IntPtr hKey);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern Int32 GetLastError();

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetupDiClassGuidsFromName(string ClassName,
            ref Guid ClassGuidArray1stItem, UInt32 ClassGuidArraySize,
            out UInt32 RequiredSize);

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
        private static extern Int32 SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(ref Guid ClassGuid,
            StringBuilder className, Int32 ClassNameSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

        /// <summary>
        /// The SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function retrieves the specified device property.
        /// This handle is typically returned by the SetupDiGetClassDevs or SetupDiGetClassDevsEx function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param Name="DeviceInfoSet">Handle to the device information set that contains the interface and its underlying device.</param>
        /// <param Name="DeviceInfoData">Pointer to an SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure that defines the device instance.</param>
        /// <param Name="Property">Device property to be retrieved. SEE MSDN</param>
        /// <param Name="PropertyRegDataType">Pointer to a variable that receives the registry data Type. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
        /// <param Name="PropertyBuffer">Pointer to a buffer that receives the requested device property.</param>
        /// <param Name="PropertyBufferSize">Size of the buffer, in bytes.</param>
        /// <param Name="RequiredSize">Pointer to a variable that receives the required buffer size, in bytes. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.</returns>
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
            ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
            SPDRP Property,
            out UInt32 PropertyRegDataType,
            byte[] PropertyBuffer,
            uint PropertyBufferSize,
            out UInt32 RequiredSize);

        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(
            IntPtr deviceInfoSet,
            [In] ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
            [In] ref DEVPROPKEY propertyKey,
            [Out] out UInt32 propertyType,
            byte[] propertyBuffer,
            UInt32 propertyBufferSize,
            out UInt32 requiredSize,
            UInt32 flags);

        const int utf16terminatorSize_bytes = 2;

        public struct DeviceInfo
        {
            public string name;
            public string description;
            public string bus_description;
        }

        static DEVPROPKEY DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc;

        static Win32DeviceMgmt()
        {
            DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc = new DEVPROPKEY();
            DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc.fmtid = new Guid(0x540b947e, 0x8b40, 0x45bc, 0xa8, 0xa2, 0x6a, 0x0b, 0x89, 0x4c, 0xbd, 0xa2);
            DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc.pid = 4;
        }

        public static List<DeviceInfo> GetAllCOMPorts()
        {
            Guid[] guids = GetClassGUIDs("Ports");
            List<DeviceInfo> devices = new List<DeviceInfo>();
            for (int index = 0; index < guids.Length; index++)
            {
                IntPtr hDeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref guids[index], 0, 0, DiGetClassFlags.DIGCF_PRESENT);
                if (hDeviceInfoSet == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to get device information set for the COM ports");
                }

                try
                {
                    UInt32 iMemberIndex = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                        deviceInfoData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
                        bool success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDeviceInfoSet, iMemberIndex, ref deviceInfoData);
                        if (!success)
                        {
                            // No more devices in the device information set
                            break;
                        }

                        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
                        deviceInfo.name = GetDeviceName(hDeviceInfoSet, deviceInfoData);
                        deviceInfo.description = GetDeviceDescription(hDeviceInfoSet, deviceInfoData);
                        deviceInfo.bus_description = GetDeviceBusDescription(hDeviceInfoSet, deviceInfoData);
                        devices.Add(deviceInfo);

                        iMemberIndex++;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDeviceInfoSet);
                }
            }
            return devices;
        }

        private static string GetDeviceName(IntPtr pDevInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData)
        {
            IntPtr hDeviceRegistryKey = SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(pDevInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData,
                DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL, 0, DIREG_DEV, KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
            if (hDeviceRegistryKey == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to open a registry key for device-specific configuration information");
            }

            byte[] ptrBuf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            uint length = (uint)ptrBuf.Length;
            try
            {
                uint lpRegKeyType;
                int result = RegQueryValueEx(hDeviceRegistryKey, "PortName", 0, out lpRegKeyType, ptrBuf, ref length);
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Can not read registry value PortName for device " + deviceInfoData.ClassGuid);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                RegCloseKey(hDeviceRegistryKey);
            }

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ptrBuf, 0, (int)length - utf16terminatorSize_bytes);
        }

        private static string GetDeviceDescription(IntPtr hDeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData)
        {
            byte[] ptrBuf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            uint propRegDataType;
            uint RequiredSize;
            bool success = SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDeviceInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData, SPDRP.SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
                out propRegDataType, ptrBuf, BUFFER_SIZE, out RequiredSize);
            if (!success)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not read registry value PortName for device " + deviceInfoData.ClassGuid);
            }
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ptrBuf, 0, (int)RequiredSize - utf16terminatorSize_bytes);
        }

        private static string GetDeviceBusDescription(IntPtr hDeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData)
        {
            byte[] ptrBuf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            uint propRegDataType;
            uint RequiredSize;
            bool success = SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(hDeviceInfoSet, ref deviceInfoData, ref DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc,
                out propRegDataType, ptrBuf, BUFFER_SIZE, out RequiredSize, 0);
            if (!success)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can not read Bus provided device description device " + deviceInfoData.ClassGuid);
            }
            return System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(ptrBuf, 0, (int)RequiredSize - utf16terminatorSize_bytes);
        }

        private static Guid[] GetClassGUIDs(string className)
        {
            UInt32 requiredSize = 0;
            Guid[] guidArray = new Guid[1];

            bool status = SetupDiClassGuidsFromName(className, ref guidArray[0], 1, out requiredSize);
            if (true == status)
            {
                if (1 < requiredSize)
                {
                    guidArray = new Guid[requiredSize];
                    SetupDiClassGuidsFromName(className, ref guidArray[0], requiredSize, out requiredSize);
                }
            }
            else
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

            return guidArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit off-topic, because it's not C#, but for the case someone was also looking for just *any* solution to get the "bus reported device description" programmatically, like I was (in my case a USB ethernet device) and stumbles upon this question, here is my PowerShell solution based on what I could collect from different sources after searching for some hours!:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.name -match "ethernet"}).GetDeviceProperties("DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc").DeviceProperties.Data
```

Theoretically speaking, you could use this as a system process in your C# code, but it's a weird method. You might also be able to work directly with WmiObjects somehow, but I have no experience with it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

To go off of vromanov's code. All you have to do is the following to get the bus description of each com port, where 0 is the First Com, 1 would be the second, and so on.

Console.WriteLine(Win32DeviceMgmt.GetAllCOMPorts()[0].bus_description);

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to add a different method. maybe it will be needed. vb.net code:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Dim DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc As DEVPROPKEY
    Dim DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName As DEVPROPKEY
    Dim DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc As DEVPROPKEY

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed
        Dim hidGuid As New Guid("a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed") 'USB_VID VE CİHAZ SERİ NO ALIR
        DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc = New DEVPROPKEY()
        DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc.fmtid = New Guid("A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0")
        DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc.pid = 2

        DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName = New DEVPROPKEY()
        DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName.fmtid = New Guid("A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0")
        DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName.pid = 14

        DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc = New DEVPROPKEY()
        DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc.fmtid = New Guid("540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2")
        DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc.pid = 4

        Dim GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE As New Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED")
        Dim GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER As New Guid("3ABF6F2D-71C4-462a-8A92-1E6861E6AF27")
        Dim GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB As New Guid("f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8")
        'Dim GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SERENUM_BUS_ENUMERATOR As New Guid("4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318")
        Dim GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SERENUM_BUS_ENUMERATOR As New Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED")

        Dim sGuid As Guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SERENUM_BUS_ENUMERATOR
        Dim hdevDisplayInfoSet As IntPtr = SetupDiGetClassDevs(sGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_PRESENT Or DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        If (hdevDisplayInfoSet <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
            Dim data As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA = New SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA()
            Dim nStatus As Integer = 0
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Dim b As Boolean = False
            While (nStatus = 0)
                data.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA))
                b = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hdevDisplayInfoSet, IntPtr.Zero, sGuid, i, data)
                If (Not b) Then
                    nStatus = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                    Exit While
                End If
                Dim dwBytes As UInteger = 0
                Dim bRet As Boolean = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdevDisplayInfoSet, data, IntPtr.Zero, 0, dwBytes, IntPtr.Zero)
                nStatus = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                If (Not bRet And Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) Then
                    Dim didd As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA = New SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA()
                    Dim nSize = 4 + If(IntPtr.Size = 4, 2, 4)
                    didd.cbSize = nSize
                    Dim da As SP_DEVINFO_DATA = New SP_DEVINFO_DATA()
                    da.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(da)
                    bRet = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdevDisplayInfoSet, data, didd, dwBytes, dwBytes, da)
                    If (bRet) Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Device Path: {0}", didd.DevicePath)
                        TextBox1.Text = didd.DevicePath
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(didd.DevicePath)
                        'ListBox1.Items.Add(description)
                        Dim nRequiredSize As UInteger = 0
                        Dim nCharSize As Integer = 260 * Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize
                        Dim pBuffer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nCharSize)
                        Dim nPropertyType As UInteger = 0
                        bRet = SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hdevDisplayInfoSet, da, DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc, nPropertyType, pBuffer, nCharSize, nRequiredSize, 0)
                        If (bRet <> 0) Then
                            Dim sDeviceDesc As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pBuffer)
                            Console.WriteLine("Description : {0}", sDeviceDesc)
                            TextBox2.Text = sDeviceDesc
                            ListBox2.Items.Add(sDeviceDesc)
                        Else
                            Dim nError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                        End If
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBuffer)

                        pBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nCharSize)
                        bRet = SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hdevDisplayInfoSet, da, DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc, nPropertyType, pBuffer, nCharSize, nRequiredSize, 0)
                        If (bRet <> 0) Then
                            Dim sReportedDeviceDesc As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pBuffer)
                            Console.WriteLine("Reported Device Desc : {0}", sReportedDeviceDesc)
                            TextBox3.Text = sReportedDeviceDesc
                            ListBox3.Items.Add(sReportedDeviceDesc)
                        Else
                            'ERROR_NOT_FOUND  1168(0x490)
                            Dim nError As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                        End If
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBuffer)

                        nStatus = 0
                        Console.WriteLine("")
                        TextBox4.Text = ""

                    End If
                End If
                i += 1
            End While
            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hdevDisplayInfoSet)
        End If
    End Sub

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetupDiGetClassDevs(ByRef ClassGuid As Guid, ByVal Enumerator As IntPtr, ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal Flags As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(ByVal DeviceInfoSet As IntPtr, ByVal DeviceInfoData As IntPtr, ByRef InterfaceClassGuid As Guid, ByVal MemberIndex As Integer, ByRef DeviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(ByVal DeviceInfoSet As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(ByVal deviceInfoSet As IntPtr, <[In]> ByRef DeviceInfoData As SP_DEVINFO_DATA, <[In]> ByRef propertyKey As DEVPROPKEY, <Out> ByRef propertyType As UInteger, ByVal propertyBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal propertyBufferSize As UInteger, <Out> ByRef requiredSize As UInteger, ByVal flags As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure DEVPROPKEY
        Public fmtid As Guid
        Public pid As UInteger
    End Structure

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(ByVal hDevInfo As IntPtr, ByRef deviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA, ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailData As IntPtr, ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize As UInt32, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out()> ByRef requiredSize As UInt32, ByVal deviceInfoData As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("Setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(ByVal hDevInfo As IntPtr, ByRef deviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA, ByRef deviceInterfaceDetailData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize As UInt32, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out()> ByRef requiredSize As UInt32, ByRef deviceInfoData As SP_DEVINFO_DATA) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Const DIGCF_PRESENT As Integer = &H2
    Public Const DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE As Integer = &H10
    Public Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER As Integer = 122

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Structure SP_DEVINFO_DATA
        Public cbSize As Integer
        Public ClassGuid As Guid
        Public DevInst As Integer
        Public Reserved As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Structure SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
        Public cbSize As Integer
        Public InterfaceClassGuid As Guid
        Public Flags As Integer
        Public Reserved As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, Pack:=1)>
    Structure SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
        Public cbSize As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)>
        Public DevicePath As String
    End Structure

End Class
```