# How to call COM object method from AHK

Tags: com, autohotkey

I'm quite new to `AutoHotKey` and I'm having a problem with `COM` objects.

What I'm trying to mimic is this `Powershell` one-liner:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity).GetDeviceProperties("DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc").DeviceProperties.Data
```

The code I have, so far, is like this:

```
#NoEnv  ; Don't check empty variables to see if they are environment variables.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings.
#SingleInstance Force  ; Force single instance.
SendMode, Input  ; Send is an alias for SendInput. Faster and safer.
SetNumLockState, AlwaysOn  ; NumLock is always on, the key does not have any future effect.
SetWorkingDir, % A_Desktop
DetectHiddenWindows, On  ; Detect hidden windows, needed for PostMessage.

for device in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PnPEntity")  {
    keys := ComObjArray(0xC, 1)  ; VT_VARIANT
    props := ComObjArray(0xC, 1)
    keys[0] := "DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc"
    result := device.GetDeviceProperties(keys, props)
    if (!result)
        MsgBox, % props[0]
}
```

The function call returns 0, which as far as I know is correct. But the `props` array seems to be empty.

I think I now the problem: `props` is a `ByRef` variable, but I tried with some code I found to create `ByRef` variables ([here](https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-ComDispatch/blob/master/ComVar.ahk)) in order to get return values, without any success.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong with the function call, because I'm absolutely clueless about how to use `COM` from `AutoHotKey`.

Yes, I know I could use `setupapi.dll` here, or some third-party library, or even the PowerShell one-liner, but I'm trying to learn how to use COM from `AutoHotKey`, how to call `COM` objects methods, etc.

So, any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

[Here is GetDeviceProperties function signature, for reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/getdeviceproperties-win32-pnpentity)

Comment: Don't now AHK, but here is a C# version, if it can be of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362886/get-devpkey-device-busreporteddevicedesc-from-win32-pnpentity-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I already knew how to do that in C# (or C for that matter), my problem is building the proper types, variables, etc. to do it in AHK, which is being very hard to do.

Comment: Well, not sure about AHK, but from what I understand, you're not calling it as I do in C#. Try to pass only one argument which is a VARIANT array which should contain 2 items. First item is a BSTR array, second one is an empty VARIANT (filled on return)

Comment: Simon, I was not using InvokeMethod on purpose, because I wanted to learn how to call COM object methods directly. Of course if I can't do that, I'll do it with InvokeMethod or using a DLLCall on setupapi.dll. All of those methods work, but I wanted to learn this :) But I'm going to try what you suggest, using just one argument, good idea.

Comment: Simon, I tried and it does not seem to work, either. The function call fails with an error signalling an invalid parameter, so the problem doesn't rely there. I think I'm missing something VERY obvious, but I can't see it for the life of me.

Comment: InvokeMethod doesn't exist as such, it's just the way .NET calls underlying method dynamically. I would try something like device.GetDeviceProperties(arrayOf2Params). Otherwise, is there an easy way to test AHK?

Comment: Simon, I already tested that and the function call returns an error, to wit, invalid parameters, so the problem does not lie there, unfortunately. This is stupidly complex, and I don't think of a way to learn this apart from trial and error or digging into AHK source code, to see how the parameters are translated. So, for now, is trial and error. Thanks for your help, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
items := ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PnPEntity")._NewEnum
    while items[device]
        MsgBox %        device.Availability[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Caption[0]
            .   "`n"    device.ClassGuid[0]
            ; . "`n"    device.CompatibleID[][0]
            .   "`n"    device.ConfigManagerErrorCode[0]
            .   "`n"    device.ConfigManagerUserConfig[0]
            .   "`n"    device.CreationClassName[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Description[0]
            .   "`n"    device.DeviceID[0]
            .   "`n"    device.ErrorCleared[0]
            .   "`n"    device.ErrorDescription[0]
            ; . "`n"    device.HardwareID[][0]
            .   "`n"    device.InstallDate[0]
            .   "`n"    device.LastErrorCode[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Manufacturer[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Name[0]
            .   "`n"    device.PNPClass[0]
            .   "`n"    device.PNPDeviceID[0]
            .   "`n"    device.PowerManagementCapabilities[][0]
            .   "`n"    device.PowerManagementSupported[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Present[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Service[0]
            .   "`n"    device.Status[0]
            .   "`n"    device.StatusInfo[0]
            .   "`n"    device.SystemCreationClassName[0]
            .   "`n"    device.SystemName[0]
                            
End::
ExitApp
```

The commented lines was giving error here... you can uncommented and test if you like.

Comment: OP is trying to call a method on the `ComObject` with some specific arguments, this is in no way related. All those fields are already available in the normal for loop implementation, all you're doing here is manually calling `_NewEnum` instead of letting the for-loop take care of calling it.

Comment: Thanks Dieisson, but that's not what I needed. I know I can loop over the results of ComObjGet(), the problem is not accessing a property of the returned item, but to call a method.