# Reading ManagementObject objects in a collection into typed variables

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a collection of `ManagementObject`s. The properties of the Management Object are different Types: int, string, array, DateTime etc.

**I want to read the property values into appropriate variable types.**

```
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\virtualization\v2"); 
manScope.Connect();
ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, queryObj);

ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmSearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject vm in vmCollection) {
    **//Fine so far.  This is not a question about iteration.**
    //Now I want to so something programmatic with the values.

    //If it is a string, this is fine:
    string myString = vm["Description"].ToString();

    //If it is an integer, I can go like this:
    int myInt =int.Parse(vm["EnabledState"].ToString());
    //But surely c# has a better way than that? Turn it into a string and then an int?

    //If it is DateTime, I have no idea what to do - DateTime.Parse() doesn't work:
   //DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(vm["LastSuccessfulBackupTime"].ToString());

}
```

I have read the documentation (which doesn't have a single example of this).
I have used the WMI Code Creator which doesn't help with this either since it merely plops everything out into the console: Console.WriteLine("InstallDate: {0}", queryObj["InstallDate"]);

Comment: [Maybe this answer helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524818/107625).

Comment: Sorry @UweKeim, but that article doesn't help and the WMI Code Creator doesn't help either.  I've updated the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual requirement but still- I would suggest to go through class details [Msvm_computersystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and create variables with same data-type. 
Once you get the data in collections, you can try parsing same to the appropriate variables.